# How to grant Select on ALL tables in ALL databases on a server?

Tags: mysql, sql

Firstly, apologies for what I assume is a really basic question. Google doesn't seem to have an answer that applies to my needs here, but I feel like I'm missing something painfully obvious. Aside from recreating a user on every individual database, is there a concise way to do what I want? I'm looking for something like.

GRANT SELECT ON (SHOW DATABASES) TO user_foo;

Comment: does this work? `GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO 'user'@'localhost';` my first google search: https://kyup.com/tutorials/create-new-user-grant-permissions-mysql/

Comment: Not quite, I only want them to have SELECT(so they cant break everything) and on all databases and all tables in all databases. Your solution is to give all privileges to one table in one database. Which would mean they can basically trash the place in their one table.

Comment: hmm, actually i already edit that, because i'm aware you will ask this question. That mean you didn't really read the link i'm posting

Comment: I did read the link and your edit is closer but that only grants select for all tables on a single database. My problem is that there are four on the server and as root user for all of them I thought that there might be a way to grant to them in aggregate?

Comment: I don't think you read it carefully, check out: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost';` , with a little modify, you will have `GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost';`

Comment: Oh my god, I'm blind. Thanks a bunch sticking with this. I appreciate it. I'll mark correct. I'd upvote too but my reputation is too low right now.

Comment: it's fine. sometimes it's just there, hiding right under our nose. i will post answer :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mention, you can use below query:

```
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

All you need can be found in this link: [my sql grant user permissions](https://kyup.com/tutorials/create-new-user-grant-permissions-mysql/)